# Getting A String Index Out Of Range Error

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program to find the number of characters of the longest palindrome within a word. What the program does is find all different substrings of the given string and should check if its a palindrome and then the number of characters it has.

Right now it is correctly finding all possible substrings and works if I enter an actual palindrome such as `hannah`, but if i input something like `banana`, I get the following error `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    String reverseWord;
    int palindromeLength = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter A Word: ");
    word = sc.nextLine();

    reverseWord = new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString();

    if (reverseWord.equals(word))
    palindromeLength = word.length();

    else {

        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

            for(int j = 1; j <= word.length() - j; j++) {

        String substring = word.substring(i, i + j);
        String reverseSubstring = new StringBuffer(substring).reverse().toString();

        if (reverseSubstring.equals(substring)) {

         if (substring.length() > palindromeLength) {

            palindromeLength = substring.length();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    System.out.println(palindromeLength);

    }
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how I could fix the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: `length()` will return the total number of characters in the string. You're going to want to use `length()-1` when looping starting at index 0.

Comment: for(int j = 1; <= shouldn't that be j = i ?

Comment: @DigitalNinja Still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the exception occurs (because endIndex is larger than the length of the string):

```
String substring = word.substring(i, i + j);
```

Use this instead:

```
String substring = word.substring(i, word.length());
```

It prints out 5 for "banana" which is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked but it doesn't work with something that has multiple palindromes of the same length, such as `abracadabra`. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I just answered to your questions: _why this is happening and how I could fix the issue_ for banana. Either way, the algorithm does not even check all **possible** substrings of the entered words (which are quite a lot). But SO is not a platform to get algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
class Palindrome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(longestPalindrome("" +
      "A man once told me, " +
      "\"A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!\" " +
      "But what does that mean?"));
    System.out.println(longestPalindrome("" +
      "And then he said, " +
      "\"No 'x' in Nixon\"... " +
      "Wtf?"));
  }

  private static int longestPalindrome(final String word) {
    assert word != null;
    final String sanitized = word
      .replaceAll("\\W", "")//strip non-word chars
      .toLowerCase();
    int currentWinner = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sanitized.length(); i++) {
      //odd palindromes
      currentWinner = Math.max(detectPalindrome(sanitized, i, 0, 0), currentWinner);
      //even palindromes
      currentWinner = Math.max(detectPalindrome(sanitized, i, 0, -1), currentWinner);
    }
    return currentWinner;
  }

  private static int detectPalindrome(final String word,
                                      final int center,
                                      final int currentIndex,
                                      final int polarity) {
    final int left = center - currentIndex;
    final int right = center + currentIndex + 1 + polarity;
    if (left >= 0
      && right < word.length()
      && word.charAt(left) == word.charAt(right)) {
      //if you're still on the string and the streak holds, check the next char
      return (detectPalindrome(word, center, currentIndex + 1, polarity));
    } else {
      //else return the longest found so far
      return currentIndex * 2 + polarity;
    }
  }
}
```